# How to implement “select all” check box

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have invoice page and customer select the invoice and pay. invoice page if invoices are multiple then customer need to select check box each then click on Generate Invoice for payment. i want if invoice are multiple customer should check All then its work customer dont have choice select single. he should select All the check boxes then its work.

i think on page javascript code is below:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function checkAll(theForm, cName) {
  for (i=0,n=theForm.elements.length;i<n;i++)
    if (theForm.elements[i].className.indexOf(cName) !=-1)
      if (theForm.elements[i].checked == true) {
        theForm.elements[i].checked = false;
      } else {
        theForm.elements[i].checked = true;
      }
}
</script>
```

on invoice page i have also option select All check box
 code is below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="kk" id="kk"  onClick="checkAll(document.getElementById('form4'), 'chk1');" >
```

when invoice are more multiple from database check code is:

```
<input name="orderNo[]" <?php  if ($SQLRow["priceStatus"]=="Received") { ?> disabled="disabled"<?php } ?> type="checkbox" id="orderNo[]" value="<?php echo $SQLRow["orderNo"];?>" class="chk1" />
```

i just want one help if all the check boxes are selected then its work.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. It should include enough HTML to reproduce the problem, and should not include any if the PHP. You should do this as a Stack Snippet so we can run the demo.

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript">` Why are you writing HTML 3.2 in 2017?

Comment: Are you asking that, if the user checks ALL checkboxes, **then** perform a function

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pajuhegege/1/edit?html,output — Your code works when I run it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is running i need when all the checkbox ticked then form forms action.

Comment: when click automatic all the box checked its working. i want a code if the user checks ALL checkboxes, then perform a function user should not leave any single box all check box must be checked

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#kk').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).prop("checked")){
            $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                $(this).prop("checked", true);

            });
        }
        else{
            $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked", "checked");
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });
        }
});
```

[Jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxy2mkw5/2/)

Comment: may be you don't use jquery ?

Comment: in invoice page using html javascript and php only

Comment: This "answer" is just a lump of code. You've rewritten it using jQuery (despite the [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) saying *Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*). You've provided no explanation as to what was wrong with the code in the question or what you've changed to fix that problem.

Comment: "Jsfiddle is here" — Why are you providing a live demo on a third party site? Stackoverflow has supported [embedded live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for years.

Comment: Your code is fundamentally different to the code in the question. You've thrown away the code which limits it to a single form, and the code which limits it to inputs which are members of a specific class.

Comment: yes, it can be fundamentally different. but if it works then he can change it. he must learn how to change the code or how to write it. I gaved him basic example which he can reuse.

Comment: They already have code which is closer to what they want to do. They'll learn more if you explain what is wrong with it then if you make them reverse engineer some code which does something different.

Comment: just saying... you should have spend on answering instead of all these comments.

Comment: when click automatic all the box checked its working. i want a code if the user checks ALL checkboxes, then perform a function user should not leave any single box all check box must be checked